# Why is my K2 process not appearing in the reports?

Tags: k2

I use K2 as my workflow engine. For some reason my processes are not available in any of the reporting views (on the workspace). Do I have to do something special when deploying to get them there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your k2 process should appear in the reports automatically. If it does not, maybe it has never been started?

Look at the _ProcInst table in the K2Server database to see if it's there.

Comment: Don't look at the K2 transaction database. Allegedly that can void your support contract. The K2 Log database is where you want to look - that's what reporting uses anyway. I believe that's the correct table name.

Comment: Looking into K2 database is OK, making any edits or changes into it puts you into unsupported state from K2 support prospective. So process has to be started at least once (otherwise there is nothing to report at) + it takes a bit of time for reports to build up (i.e. they are not real time, and need to be generated by system first) + see comment about permissions from @Ghlouw below

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have view permissions set for that process. If you do not have view permissions you will not see the process in reports.

Answer (score 1):

TrueWill's comments are correct.  However, the most likely cause of not seeing specific process data is the lack of required permissions.  Make sure your account has either View, View Participate, or the Admin right on the process depending upon the requirement.  View Participate requires that you participated in the process in some way, like being a destination user (which would usually mean a task is assigned to you), for you to see the reporting data for that instance.